# CGI asking for permissions to run python script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, cgi, gpio

I am running a small webserver on a Raspberry Pi. I am trying to access the GPIO ports with a python script, executed via CGI from another computer on the local network.

The program runs fine when executed locally with sudo. However when I run it from another computer, CGI returns the following error :

type 'exceptions.IOError' : [Errno 13] Permission denied

I gave the file full permissions (I know it's not good, but I am the only user), I gave www-data permissions to run files. It seems I can't access the GPIO ports. I don't know which file permissions are blocking me. Can you help ?

EDIT : I found  the solution, I had to add www-data to the spi group. 3 hours of searching for one bloody line in the terminal.

Comment: Please show the full traceback.  `IOError` should contain more information.

Comment: <type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 13] Permission denied 
      args = (13, 'Permission denied') 
      errno = 13 
      filename = None 
      message = '' 
      strerror = 'Permission denied'

Comment: OK, looks like you need to check permission on the GPIO ports, check their permissions in /dev.

Comment: I already set gpiomem permissions to 777. The thing is other python scripts are fully working, and this one refuses to. The python code I use works by itself, even from another computer. But now that I added html around it, it says I don't have permissions...